# My react app works correctly, but tests not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Unit test returns error, but when I launch my app everything works.

The problem is, that when callOnSubmitWithData() is returned in arrow function as onPress callback, mocked onSubmit function is not called, but in launched app everything works.

Unit test in Jest with enzyme:

```js
const setup = (propOverrides) => {
 const props = Object.assign({
  fields: [],
  error: '',
  onSubmit() {}
 }, propOverrides);

 const wrapper = shallow(
   <Form {...props}/>
 );

 return {
  props,
  wrapper
 };
};

it('sends fields data to callback after push submit button', () => {
  const inputValue = 'Some text';
  const submitCallback = jest.fn();

  const {wrapper, props} = setup({
    onSubmit: submitCallback,
    fields: [
      {
        key: 'first',
        value: inputValue
      },
      {
        key: 'second',
        value: inputValue
      }
    ]
  });

  const output = {
    [props.fields[0].key]: inputValue,
    [props.fields[1].key]: inputValue
  };

  wrapper.setState({isSubmitDisabled: false});
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find(Button).simulate('click');

  expect(submitCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(output);
});
```

And my part of my component:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

    //Create State
    
    //Other bindings
  this.callOnSubmitWithData = this.callOnSubmitWithData.bind(this);
 }
  
  //...
  
 callOnSubmitWithData() {
  const data = this.extractFieldsData();
  this.props.onSubmit(data);
 }

 extractFieldsData() {
  //Returns object with all fields values
 }

 render() {
  const {fields, error, buttonTitle} = this.props;

  return (
   <View>
    <View>
    {
     fields.map((data) => {
      //...
      return (<AuthTextInput/>);
     })
    }
    </View>

    <Button 
     title={buttonTitle}
     onPress={() => this.callOnSubmitWithData()}
     disabled={this.state.isSubmitDisabled}
    />
   </View>
  );
 }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `simulate()`. You attach handler to `onPress` but calling `simulate('click')`.

You need to call exactly `onPress`. Maybe `simulate('press')` will work.

If not you can just

```
wrapper.find(Button).props().onPress();
wrapper.update();
```

and then your mock will be run.